# Do I need a UK transit visa for traveling from denmark to Bangladesh via Heathrow Airport

Tags: visas, uk, transit, denmark

I want to travel to Bangladesh from Denmark via Heathrow Airport, so do I need a transit visa from the UK?
My onward flight from Heathrow Airport within 2 hours and same as when I will return to Denmark. I am a Bangladeshi National with having danish permanent residence permit and my wife with a dependent visa from Denmark.
Do I need to get UK transit visa? or I am ok to fly without a transit visa?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The UK Government has an online tool that allows you to check if you need a transit visa based on your travel information and your country of origin.
All you have to do is click "Start now" and answer the questions on your screen.

Here's a link to it: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa